# Variables are not available in Pycharm Debugger

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using the PyCharm Debugger to view the variables of my script. It usually

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm code editor.]

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm execution stack.]

I am trying to inspect the attributes of `rulebased_device.subsystem` by unfolding the corresponding dropdown menu. It works fine for `rulebased_device.system`, but with the former, there is a message *Collecting data...* and then the following interface shows up:

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm debugger window.]

I have absolutely no clue what the issue might be here. I have googled it, but the results were that I should remove the content root in the Project Structure, and I don't think that's gonna make a difference except messing up my settings. When I run it in the Python Console, it shows me `exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. It was due to a circular reference. In a `@property` method, I reference the method itself instead of the private attribute prefixed by a an underscore (_).